# I want to select values With condition in Other Varchar

Tags: sql

My question is simple

I want to `select` all banks without two ones, those 02 banks are stored in `other table` in varchar with ',' between.

Take this example :

I have this request

```
SELECT '('
    || AD_Message.msgtext
    || ')'
  FROM AD_Message
  WHERE AD_Message.value = 'CHM_EXCLUDED_BANK'
```

with Result = `('Bank1', 'Bank2')`

Now i want to do this

```
 SELECT name
    FROM c_bank
    WHERE name NOT IN
      (SELECT '('
        || AD_Message.msgtext
        || ')'
      FROM AD_Message
      WHERE AD_Message.value = 'CHM_EXCLUDED_BANK'
      )
```

I want this Result : `ALL banks` except this 02 ones `('Bank1', 'Bank2')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NOT LIKE for this like this:

```
SELECT name
    FROM c_bank
    INNER JOIN AD_Message
    ON ad_message.value = 'CHM_EXCLUDED_BANK'
    WHERE AD_Message.msgtext not like '%'||name||'%'
```